# как кинуть ошибку в rtk-query и в middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

для чего: валидация будет происходить в ErrorBoundary, мне не нужно что бы rtkQuery хоть как то валидировал некоторые ошибки

тут все просто

```
const A = () => {
  const [some, { isLoading, error }] = useSomeMutation();

  if(error) {
    //тут все просто, но что если мне надо делать так на более глобaльном уровне?
    throw new Error(`unhandled error`)
  }

  return <div></div>
}
```

а вот далее уже не ясно как

```
const baseApi = createApi({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    
    some: builder.mutation({
      //как выдать ошибку для some? throw new Error(`unhandled error`)
      query: (body) => ({
        url: "auth/sign-up",
        method: "POST",
        body,
      }),
      
    }),
  }),
});

const { useSomeMutation } = baseApi;
// кроме как вот так
const useCustomSomeMutation = () => {
  const mut = useSignInMutation();

  if (mut[1].error) {
    throw new Error('das');
  }

  return mut
};
```

еще выше

```
export const serverCrashMiddleware = (api) => (next) => (action) => {
    if (isRejectedWithValue(action)) {
      //как выдать ошибку вообще для всего? throw new Error(`unhandled error`)
    }
    return next(action);
  };
```